# C++14 extract quoted strings verbatim including the quotes

Tags: c++, string, c++14, stringstream

Let me have a string:

```
string tstring = "Some arbitrarily long string which has \"double quotes\" which has to be printed verbatim";
```

I tried use stringstreams and quoted to extract words

```
stringstream stream(tstring);
string tepm;
while(stream >> std::quoted(temp))
    cout << temp << endl;
```

But the above skips the quotes in the the quoted string

```
Some
arbitrarily
.
.
double quotes
.
.
verbatim
```

I want the quoted string printed verbatim with the quotes included

```
Some
arbitrarily
.
.
"double quotes"
.
.
verbatim
```

How do i do this using the quoted function or if it is not possible is there a better way to do this (apart from of course reading character by character and doing all the work myself)

**EDIT:**

Here is the MCVE as requested

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string sspace = "Hi this is \"Real Madrid\"";
    stringstream stream(sspace);
    string fpart;
    while(stream >> quoted(fpart)){
        cout << fpart << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::quoted` is removing the quotes. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted . `quoted` is designed to treat quoted substrings as single items, ignoring whitespace.

Comment: @DavidLively I know quoted is removing the quotes hence the output, is there a way to find out if it is quoted and preserve the quotes and the string within?

Comment: Hmmm.. actually, the definition of `quoted` seems to say that, when used in input like `stream >> std::quoted(temp)`, the escaped quotes should be maintained. Could you post a complete, compilable, *short* sample?

Comment: @DavidLively I have added the MCVE if you wanted to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think [`std::quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) is the right tool for the job here because there's no easy way to tell if the next string had quotes that were stripped before you print it (it discards your delimiter, which is `'\"'` by default)

I think we can safely fall back on `std::string`'s `find` method.

- Include a subroutine to print all words (space delimited) that aren't within quotes
- Continually read until the next quote character taking advantage of `find`:

Full Code:

```
void PrintUnquoted(std::string _in)
{
    std::istringstream ss(_in);
    std::string temp;
    while(ss >> temp)
    {
        std::cout << temp << '\n';
    }
}

int main(){
    std::string sspace = "Hi this is \"Real Madrid\" etc.";
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t nextQuote = 0;
    while(nextQuote = sspace.find('\"', start), nextQuote != std::string::npos)
    {
        size_t endQuote = sspace.find('\"', nextQuote+1);
        if (endQuote == std::string::npos)
        {
            throw std::logic_error("Unmatched quotes");
        }

        PrintUnquoted(sspace.substr(start, nextQuote-start));
        std::cout << sspace.substr(nextQuote, endQuote-nextQuote+1) << std::endl;
        start = endQuote+1;
    }
    if (start < sspace.size())
    {
        PrintUnquoted(sspace.substr(start));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/637e0b6583060045)

If you need to store the quoted characters within a variable, the line

```
 std::cout << sspace.substr(nextQuote, endQuote-nextQuote+1) << std::endl;
```

Should be easily modifiable to obtain that.

Comment: Nice, i thought of this, but my code got way too complicated and messy, so just wanted to try out other options.

Answer (score 2):

When used in input, `std::quoted` removes unescaped quotes from the string and un-escapes escaped quotes. So a string like this:

```
"some \"string with\" inner quotes"
```

becomes this when read in:

```
some "string with" inner quotes
```

But for this to work, the string must actually be quoted and escaped in the stream. If you do this:

```
std::string str = "string \"with some\" quotes";
std::stringstream ss (str);
std::cout << "stream contents: " << ss.str() << std::endl;
```

the stream contents will actually be:

```
string "with some" quotes
```

The escaping you're doing when declaring `str` doesn't end up in the stream, it's there only for the parser. If you want it to be written exactly like that in the output stream you would have to write it like this instead:

```
std::string str = "\"string \\\"with some\\\" quotes\"";
```

or better yet:

```
std::string str = "string \"with some\" quotes";
ss << std::quoted(str);
```

and leave `std::quoted` do it's job.

Comment: Oddly enough, while this seems to work, it's in direct conflict with the example on the cppreference.com example. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted)

Comment: You are correct but i wanted to store the quoted strings in a separate variable, how will i do that using your approach? Or at the least i need a way to skip spaces in the strings except inside the quotes

Comment: @DavidLively How is it in conflict with that example?
@VikashB You can write it to a `stringstream` with `quoted` and then get the contents of the stream with `strea.str()`.